# Prcoessing GeoLocation in Loopback 4 and storing as MySQL point

Tags: mysql, node.js, geolocation, loopback, loopback4

My **MySQL** database stores a geolocation coordinates as a spatial data types `Point`.
I need my loopback 4 (lb4) to be able to handle such property type.

According to the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/LoopBack-types.html), lb4 has `GeoPoint` type, which after some research I found out that it is not supported (see [issue #1981](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1981)).

I also tested out and can confirm that lb4 does not recognize `GeoPoint` type and when defining in the `@property` decorator `type: 'geopoint'`, it does not recognize that type either.

My question is: **How can I handle geolocation data in loopback 4 and while my MySQL database stores it as the spatial type `Point`?**

```
@model()
export class SomeEntity extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'geopoint', // does not recognize
    required: true,
    mysql: {
      dataType: 'point',
    },
  })
  coordinate: GeoPoint; // is not defined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have since talked with some helpful guys on the Loopback slack channel and found also that GeoPoint does not seem to work however the following allowed me to create a Point datatype field in Mysql

```
      @property({
    type: 'object',
    mysql: {
      dataType: 'point',
    },
  })
  latlng: point;
```

At end need to define point to export

```
export interface point {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}
```

So my whole model looks like this...

```
    import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';
    import moment from 'moment';
    
    @model({settings: {strict: false}})
    export class Location extends Entity {
      @property({
        type: 'number',
        id: true,
        generated: true,
      })
      id: number;
    
      @property({
        type: 'string',
      })
      addr1: string;
    
      @property({
        type: 'string',
      })
      addr2: string;
    
      @property({
        type: 'string',
      })
      city: string;
    
      @property({
        type: 'string',
      })
      region: string;
    
      @property({
        type: 'string',
      })
      postcode: string;
    
      @property({
        type: 'string',
      })
      country: string;
    
// NEW PROPERTY ..........................

      @property({ 
        type: 'object',
        mysql: {
          dataType: 'point',
        },
      })
      latlng: point;
    
      @property({
        type: 'number',
      })
      display_ix: number;
    
      @property({
        type: 'date',
        defaultFn: 'now',
      })
      created_date: string;
    
      @property({
        type: 'number',
        required: false,
      })
      created_by: number;
    
      @property({
        type: 'date',
        defaultFn: 'now',
      })
      modified_date: string;
    
      @property({
        type: 'number',
        required: false,
      })
      modified_by: number;
    
      constructor(data?: Partial<Location>) {
        super(data);
      }
    }
    
// NEW EXPORT ..........................

    export interface point {
      lat: number;
      lng: number;
    }
    
    export interface LocationRelations {
      // describe navigational properties here
    }
    
    export type LocationWithRelations = Location & LocationRelations;
```

I Hope this helps... as you can see it has managed the new point property in mysql
[see mysql table screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Aqx.png)

Comment: hey im stuck in same problem with postgres, i can create the point datatype but not sure how to actually store the value in it. I am getting error invalid input syntax for type point